# Is it possible to run automatically a query after postgres restarts?

Tags: postgresql

i would like to run a small query every time postgres is restarted, is this possible?
I have found that is possible to do that every time psql is launched, using .psqlrc but that does not address my need

thanks

Comment: Modify the startup script.

Comment: which startup script? AFAIK there is no startup script associated to postgres, there is a .psqlrc associated to plsql but that is a different thing.

Comment: True - I though you might have installed from binary packages, which usually come with a startup script. Then I cannot think of anything better than writing your own script to start PostgreSQL and run a command afterwards. There is no way to do this from PostgreSQL.

Comment: too bad... i want this to be done everytime someone restarts, not just me using the script.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming here looking for a solution, as of today (2020, postrgresql 12) it is not possible to configure postgres to always run a given script/query.

You can of course use your own launch script but you can not prevent, it seems, other people restarting their way if they have the right permissions.